# Expected value identities

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If I'm given the expected value of two random variables, say A and B is 0 and C = 5*A + B. How would I find the expected value of C? And if the variance of A and B is 1, the variance of C?

There is an identity for expected values then? i.e. if E(5*A + B) = E(5*A) + E(B)?
If that's the case, then Expected value of C is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Expected value of $C$ is $(5 \times \text{expected value of }A) + (1 \times \text{expected value of }B) = 0$.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then $(\text{variance of }C)$ $= (5^2 \times \text{variance of }A)$ ${}+ (1^2 \times \text{variance of }B)$ $= 25 + 1 = 26$.

Comment: There is an identity for expected values then? i.e. if E(5*A + B) = E(5*A) + E(B)?

Comment: How would I use this information to determine if A and B are independent?

Comment: Yes, the identity for expected values holds whether they are independent or not.  I don't know how you check for independence.

Comment: The identity for variances holds of $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated, which is a weaker condition than independence.  I.e. if they are independent, then the are uncorrelated, but in some cases they are uncorrelated without being independent.